# Ubuntu 21.04 fails to open properly on first boot but loads fine after forcefully shutting down and booting again

Tags: 21.04

I am using Ubuntu 21.04 (no dual boot) and I am encountering some strange issues during the boot process.

I encounter the state depicted in the picture each time I open my laptop from a shutdown state or when I reboot it. However, when my laptop is in this state, if I forcefully power it off and power on again, then the boot process runs fine. How can this issue be fixed? Thanks.[image]

*** Edit #1:
When the startup frozen-like state appears, I pressed the up-arrow key, and the output was the following:

```
Volume group "vgubuntu" not found
Cannot process volume group vgubuntu
Volume group "vgubuntu" not found
Cannot process volume group vgubuntu

Please unlock disk nvme0n1p3_crypt
```

It did ask for my decryption password. However, after I gave the password, a bunch of output appeared, and then the situation was the same. The login screen did not come, and I had to poweroff-and-poweron, not  once, but twice.

Comment: When the computer starts booting and before it reaches the state in the picture, press the up arrow key to reveal the boot messages. The last message may give us a clue.

Comment: I am not sure whats going on. Someone with more experience with encryption may have better ideas.